# How to remove a small gap (fold-like line) on a closed 3D surface?

Tags: plotting

This problem is probably pretty basic, but I can't find a solution anywhere.

Here's a closed surface with a nice yummy flavor :

```
SphericalPlot3D[
8Cos[4phi]Sin[theta]^4 - 35 - 28Cos[2theta] - Cos[4theta],
{theta, 0, Pi}, {phi, 0, 2 Pi},
ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, theta, phi, r}, ColorData["Rainbow"][r]],
PlotPoints -> {32, 24},
BoundaryStyle -> None,
PlotRange -> All,
Boxed -> False,
Axes -> False,
SphericalRegion -> True,
Method -> {"RotationControl" -> "Globe"},
ImageSize -> {500, 500}
]
```

Now turn around it.  You should notice a vertical "fold-like" line all along the surface.  This is apparently a "cut" (turning the **BoundaryStyle** to *True* should reveal the border with a black line).

This is very annoying.  How should I remove that cut "fold" on the surface (which should be perfectly smooth everywhere) ?

Comment: If this help, try start theta with less than 0. Try this `{theta, -Pi, Pi}`

Comment: @Algohi, it cannot be !  Theta is a spherical angle, from 0 to Pi.  Changing the interval to -Pi to Pi will double the surface.  I tried it, and it also add some glitches at the poles.  That cut line appears to be between phi = 0 and phi = 2Pi, which should be "glued" (or identified) in some way which I don't know.

Comment: Cham as @Algohi suggested, you should try setting `{theta, -Pi, Pi}`; in order to remove the resulting glitches, increase `MaxRecursion` (e.g. to `MaxRecursion -> 4`). Your `PlotPoints` setting may also need to be adjusted.

Comment: @MarcoB, using **{theta, -Pi, Pi}** gives ugly artifacts at the poles (a kind of polar pinch effect).  The problem appears to be between **phi = 0** and **phi = 2Pi**.  Both values should be identified.

Comment: @Cham The following was obtained setting `{theta, -Pi, Pi}`, eliminating any `PlotPoints` directive, and setting `MaxRecursion -> 5`; I don't see artifacts at the poles: [image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/gHn2I.png). I am on Win 7-64 and MMA 10.4.

Comment: @MarcoB, oh, yes it's working (apparently), but the impact on Manipulate is very high.  And how do you define the number of lines for theta, independently as for phi ?

Comment: @MarcoB, try this surface with the Manipulate shown here : http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/109317/how-to-make-the-mesh-to-rotate-with-a-surface-in-manipulate.  Your trick doesn't work well (serious impact on performances, or very ugly rendering during manipulation).  There is certainly another way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason for the line you see is probably that the surface normals aren't calculated correctly at the stitching line. Surface normals are used to give a smooth rendering even for low number of polygons. This can be fixed by specifying a [`NormalsFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NormalsFunction.html) as follows:

```
f[theta_, phi_] := 
 8 Cos[4 phi] Sin[theta]^4 - 35 - 28 Cos[2 theta] - Cos[4 theta]

n[θ_, ϕ_] = 
  Apply[Cross, 
   D[f[θ, ϕ] {Cos[ϕ] Sin[θ], 
        Sin[ϕ] Sin[θ], 
        Cos[θ]}, #] & /@ {θ, ϕ}];

 SphericalPlot3D[f[theta, phi], {theta, 0, Pi}, {phi, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 NormalsFunction -> (n[#4, #5] &), 
 ColorFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y, z, theta, phi, r}, ColorData["Rainbow"][r]], 
 PlotPoints -> {32, 24}, BoundaryStyle -> None, PlotRange -> All, 
 Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, SphericalRegion -> True, 
 Method -> {"RotationControl" -> "Globe"}, ImageSize -> {500, 500}]
```

The resulting plot looks like the original one, but has no defective line on my system (Mac OS X, *Mathematica* version 10.3.1).

The only change I made was the option `NormalsFunction -> (n[#4, #5] &)`, no change to the number of plot points was made. To construct the normals, I defined your plot function as `f`, and then calculated its surface normal from the spherical-coordinate parametrization using the `Cross` product of the tangent vectors. The latter are obtained by differentiation with respect to the angles. This is done in the function `n`, which returns the normal vector.

Comment: It appears to work !  Thanks a lot !  I'll study this interesting solution tomorrow, since now I'm too tired to understand anything :-(

Comment: Very nice. +1 or more